# How can I display first 3 values from a foreach loop and on click more display All the Values from the row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework, php-7

I am looping through a list of values and there are more than 22 values. I want to just show maximum 3 values and a click more button so it can display all the values as the user request.

I am a little bit confuse on how to do that.

This is what I did before which when you click on the plus it will show all the records and when you click on the minus it will hide all the records

Do we have to limit the number values on the sql query or is there a PHP way to show three records and then using Javascript to display all?

Help a sister out ^^

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Std Id</th>
                <th>List of Names</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
             foreach ($Names as $key => $name): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $key ?></td>
                <td class="collapse-control collapse-plus">
                    <?php
                        $students = [];
                        foreach($name as $r){
                            if(!in_array($r->getStudent(), $students ))
                                $students []=$r->getStudent();
                            ?>
                            <span class="form-names d-none"><?= $row->getName()?><br> </span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Script

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse-control').on('click', function(e) {
        var $cell = $(this).toggleClass('collapse-plus collapse-minus');
        $cell.find('.form-names').toggleClass('d-none');
    });
});
```

Comment: Retrieve them all (PHP), then only reveal them when required (JavaScript).

Comment: That's the problem, I tried writing some javascript code but nothing really worked for me and now Im becoming frustrated

Comment: I suggest you, use some ajax code, its pretty easy to set up, in your sql code just use something semilar to this `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 3;` than after with ajax call `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 3, 100;` so it will start from 3 and countinue with rest... (example is if you are using database).
There is another method, use `$_GET['name'];`, when you press a button, you will set a parameter to load rest of articles, and control it with PHP `if (isset($_GET['name'])) { echo "my articles"; }`. Hope It was helpful...

Comment: No sorry it is not clear for me

Answer (score 1):

You can show all the data in PHP using loop (like what you did). Now, you just need to add a condition inside the loop. Tell the loop to show the first three items without any style or class of `display:none`, then the rest will have a class or style. The idea is like this:

```
$counter = 0;    
foreach($name as $r)){ // your loop here

  if($counter < 3){ //show the first 3 items
    echo  "<span class='form-names'>".$row->getName()."</span>";
  }else{ //show the rest items but hide it
    echo  "<span class='form-names' style='display:none'>".$row->getName()."</span>";
  }

$counter++;//add a counter
}
```

Then you can now trigger a button, when clicked, it will show all `.form-names`. OR you can use your existing JQuery toggle function.

No need to use array_slice, you just add a `counter` variable to check if the item is greater than 3. The use of this is to show the first 3 items as normal (no style of `display:none`), but the rest items will loop with style of `display:none` so it will hide on the webpage (but it is already loaded in DOM).

Comment: I see what you saying I should show first 3 items using the function array_slice? so then how can I stored the remaining elements of the array so that I can hide it?

Comment: @LabelleDoriane No need to use array_slice, you just add a `counter` variable to check if the loop of item is looped 3x. The first 3 looped items will just show as normal, but the other (the rest items) will loop with style of `display:none` so it will hide on the webpage (but it is already loaded in DOM).